# Stability for open manifolds of finite volume under lower Ricci curvature bound

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

By a theorem of Cheeger-Colding if $N_i\to M$, where $\to$ means Gromov-Haussdorff convergence, $N_i$ and $M$ are of the same dimension, compact and smooth Riemannian manifold with finite volume, as $i\to\infty$. If Ricci curvature of $N_i$ is bounded from below by $k\in \mathbb R$, then for $i$ large, $N_i$ is diffeomorphic to $M$.

Question is, what if $N_i$'s are open manifolds? I really care about the smooth structures, so let's assume all $N_i$ are all homeomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean by $N_i\to M$ for open manifolds? If you mean pointed GH convergence, then let $N_i$ be the fixed metric on $N$ rescaled by $i$, so that the limit is a Euclidean space, which need not homeomorphic to $N$.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, thanks, the $\to$ means GH convergence. Yes, you are right, I need to exclude the tangent cone here, so what if all $N_i$ and $M$ are of finite volume?

Comment: The question is still unclear: did you mean pointed GH convergence or unpointed GH convergence?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, I mean global, unpointed. But for pointed version, you have counterexample? moving the center point to infinity can prevent manifold from collapsing in finite volume case?

Comment: In the pointed case there are counterexamples, coming from e.g. cusp opening of hyperbolic manifolds of dimension 2 and 3: closed hyperbolic manifolds can converge to noncompact hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume. I do not undertand what you said about moving the basepoint and preventing collapse.

Comment: I was really interested in exotic smooth structures, so let's assume $N_i$ and $M$ are all homeomorphic at the beginning.